# Restore file and directory pointers after delete

Tags: data-recovery, raid

I accidentally deleted hundreds of video files on my ReadyNAS device (2 disks in RAID 1 with BTRFS file system). I immediately turned it off so it would not be re-written to.

I understand there are many recovery programs out there...but they all seem to scan for the files (potentially by file type), then create a list of those files that you can then restore to another location. This process is very slow and inconvenient.

1. It is very slow to copy all that data to another drive
2. It doesn't retain the original file name or directory structure, which was important in how I cataloged them

I'm assuming the answer to my next question is "No", but is it not possible to simply rebuild the pointer database (whatever it is that gets removed when you delete a file) instead of doing all this other stuff? Or is the issue that all that metadata about the file (it's name, directory, etc) is what was deleted permanently?

**UPDATE**

I tried TestDisk. When I get to the partition list screen, there are 3 partitions, when I select the main data partition, the only options available are `[Type] [Image Creation] [Quit]` there is no `[undelete]` like I've seen in the tutorials???

Comment: TestDisk might be able to recover the directory structure & filenames of deleted files, copied to another destination. In the future a list of filenames & hashes (crc32, md5, etc) might allow matching nameless recovered (uncorrupted) files to their original names

Comment: I can't get TestDisk to read the partition unfortunately with the default partition type it is trying to use. I've tried many combinations of other partition types, and sometimes it will then give me a `[List]` option, but when I select it. It gives an error: Can't read files. File system may be corrupt. So not sure how to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, after days of trying different approaches, the Reclaime.com solution worked fantastic. It allowed me to see all of the folders I originally deleted and just select those folders to restore. Plus it also knew the original file names! Restored, like the delete never happened.

I tried many solutions...TestDisk, PhotoRec, Home NAS Recovery, Easus, iCare Data Recovery, DiskInternals. None were able to view my old directory structure and file names. They all, IIRC, were able to do scans and find all files on the disk, but them name them to something like f1003940404.mp4. But that was not the desired outcome. These disks have 2 TB of data on them, I am only concerned with the known folders I deleted. And they were organized by date, so I didn't want to have to go through all the restored f21130054.... named files to reorganize them. Yes, I tried tools like exiftool, which was helpful, but many files restored didn't have the necessary exif data to be able to rename files by date created.